# Wordpress change image url mappings

Tags: wordpress

I inherited WordPress project and all media(images) inside posts looked like this:

http://example.com/image/news/name.jpg

Even though site's root is set as http://example.com/news
and images are actually saved inside `wp-content/uploads/2017...`

Now I moved this site from shared hosting to my own server and I am trying to serve it via nginx config that looks like this:

```
location ^~ /news {
    root /var/www/html/;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ @wp;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass             unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param  
        SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```

Everything else works, except image urls.

Why exactly do old URLS look like they do? What was rewriting them?

And how can I use nginx and `/image` location to fix this?

Comment: Hi. I had added a possible solution. Did you get a chance to take a look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an alias in the nginx config: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias

```
location /image/news/ {
    alias /wp-content/uploads/2017/;
}
```

You might need to modify based on the dates of the folder.

Question:

Did you observe the image path `http://example.com/image/news/name.jpg` in the rendered page (view source), or in the raw back-end data/text mode in post edit.

If it's in the raw data:

Instead of giving nginx the extra work, you mentioned just migrating the site, so why not open the SQL file in a text editor, then find and replace the string paths and re-import the database. (You should actually export the current data to use in case you made edits already.. keep a copy as a backup)

The above is a recommended method, because you might find and replace in certain fields that you might miss in the next optional method.

Optionally, you can run an SQL REPLACE command on the posts table. PLEASE BACKUP DATABASE first.

Here's an example to replace in the `posts` table. Modify the values in `{..}` accordingly.

```
UPDATE `{prefix}_posts` SET `post_content` = REPLACE( `post_content` , '{old-path}', '{new-path}' ) WHERE `post_content` LIKE '%{old-path}%'
```

...

However, if the paths in the raw data was already correct, and only the rendered HTML paths are different.

Then seems like either a plugin or theme code is modifying the image paths.

Run a file search for the string `image/news/` and see if any files appear. Also do a search for this in the database sql file. It might shine some light on what's going on and you can then modify the values accordingly.